# Парсер HTML, на Python не могу спарсить span с номером телефона

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautiful-soup

Учу Python, чтоб не сухой код учить, решил учить на практике. Начал писать парсер. У меня не получается спарсить только **один элемент**, с номером телефона. Только получается спарсить все теги span и все что в них заключено.

```html
<span class="ls-detail_price">8 000 $</span> <span>373-76-766250, 373-77-592228</span> 
<span class="ls-detail_price">6 000 $</span> <span>373-76-966250, 373-77-592233</span>
```

Вот такая конструкция спарсивается, т.е все span теги, а мне нужен только один с номером телефона. Вот внутри какой конструкции находится номер телефона!

```html
<div class="ls-detail_anData">
  <span class="ls-detail_price">1 600 $</span>
  <div class="mapath list">
 <span id="pointer_icon">Тирасполь</span>
  </div>
  <div>
  <span class="phone_icon">373-77-534801</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Пытался через класс который относится к номеру телефона, но не получается возвращает пустой массив. Телефон вставлен через before:: как до него добраться с помощью Python?
  Цель избавиться от тегов span и лишней строки с ценой. Пожалуйста не минусите, я действительно хочу разобраться, только не могу понять, что делать дальше.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import html

fname = 'test'

def get_html(url):
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    return response.read()
def parse(html):
    projects = []
    #Парсим всю страницу целиком
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    #Делаем обор по тегу и классу
    div = soup.find('div', class_='ls-detail')
    #Находим только что связано с тегом span
    for row in div.find_all('span'):
        print(row)

def main():
    parse(get_html('https://makler.md/ru/transport/cars'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Хорошо я сдела вот таким образом но спарсил он в основном только текст и небольшие конструкии с тегами.

```html
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  # $ pip install beautifulsoup4
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = 'https://makler.md/ru/transport/cars'
fname = 'test'

def get_html(url):
 with urlopen(url) as html_page:
  charset = html_page.headers.get_content_charset(None) # may be None
  soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, 'html.parser', from_encoding=charset)
  f = open("%s %s" % (fname,".html"), "w")
  f.write(soup.text)
  f.close

def main():
 get_html('https://makler.md/ru/transport/cars')

if __name__ == '__main__':
 main()
```

Comment: Уважаемый @jfs зачем минусить.... прежде чем это делать попробуте разобраться. Для тех кто разбирается в коде, думаю не нужно писать что получается, просто скопировав и скомпелировав, можно увидеть, это раз. А во вторых вроде понятно я описал что я хотел бы, хочу научиться парсить. Возникла проблема что не могу спарсить только один элемент с номером телефона, по классу не получается, хотя у этого блока есть он. Проблемма из за того, что номер телефона прописан через before:: а до не го я не знаю как добраться. Да и вообще я дальнейшую логигику не могу понять что делать, куда копать.

Comment: @jfs **<span class="ls-detail_price">8 000 $</span>
<span>373-76-766250, 373-77-592228</span>** Вот такая конструкция спарсивается, т.е все span теги, а мне нужен только один с номером телефона. **<span class="phone_icon">373-77-534801</span>** Вот внутри какой конструкции находится номер телефона!

Comment: @jfs Согласен может и не точно и не так описал вопрос, но вопрос Зачем минусить? Даладно, можете не отвечать, лучше скажите так нормально описание?

Comment: Находите теги с `ls-detail_price` и у тегов вызывайте `next_sibling` чтобы получить следующий элемент после текущего тега (следующий не значит его вложенный) и им будет span с телефонами. 
Если `next_sibling` не помог, есть его аналог, не помню точно, что-то вроде: find_next_sibling в нем указывает тег, которые идет после текущего.
И я бы советовал использовать css-селекторы, вместо методов
Мне кажется они проще воспринимаются, да и используются много где. Пример: `div = soup.select('div.ls-detail')` или просто `div = soup.select('.ls-detail')`.

Comment: @gil9red  [Вот пример](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5999786) нашел что то похожее вот по такому типу? `print soup.find(text="Address:").findNext('td').contents[0]`

Comment: @gil9red Вы уже ответили, а я искал инфу. Спасибо щас буду пробовать!

Comment: @jfs возможно и не вы, значит так совпало! Если что прошу извинить!

Comment: @jfs  я привел целый кусок кода html. Цена, место и номер все они вставлены через before:: если указать здесь **div = soup.find('div', class_='ls-detail')** класс который относится к тому блоку (телефон) что мне надо то он возвращает только  одну строку с номером местом и городом т.е не парсит весь лист, а если дописать класс относящийся к тому span который мне нужен т.е. тут **for row in div.find_all('span'):** возвращает пустые строки. Как то вот так, извините если что то не ясно излагаю, просто не представляю как это правильно сделать. Кашмар какие жестокие люди минусят, за что!!!

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы извлечь текст из `<span>` элемента с классом `phone_icon`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  # $ pip install beautifulsoup4

soup = BeautifulSoup("""<div class="ls-detail_anData">
  <span class="ls-detail_price">1 600 $</span>
  <div class="mapath list">
    <span id="pointer_icon">Тирасполь</span>
  </div>
  <div>
  <span class="phone_icon">373-77-534801</span>
  </div>
</div>""", 'html.parser')
print(soup.find('span', 'phone_icon').get_text())
# -> 373-77-534801
```

Чтобы скачать html по ссылке:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  # $ pip install beautifulsoup4


with urlopen(url) as html_page:
    charset = html_page.headers.get_content_charset(None) # may be None
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, 'html.parser', from_encoding=charset)
print(soup.find('span', 'phone_icon').get_text())
```

код передаёт кодировку из `Content-Type` http-заголовка, если она доступна.

Comment: но если так то мне нужно будет сохранить страницу а потом с ней работать так, потому что я вставил конструкцию в тот код но выдает ошибку **print = (soup.find('span', 'phone_icon').get_text())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'**

Comment: @Stasinskii: код в ответе работает/(и работал) как есть. Я добавил код, который явно по ссылке html берёт. Следующий очевидный шаг: сохранить результат `get_html()` в файл и внимательно на него посмотреть—есть ли в нём `<span class="phone_icon"...`? Работает ли код с этой разметкой? (укажите имя файла куда сохранили вместо html, чтобы проверить: `BeautifulSoup(open('input.html', encoding='utf-8'))`) Конструкции типа: `print = (` это ошибка. Будьте внимательны к деталям. Иначе это затрудняет отладку (не ясно, то ли это настоящая проблема, или вы просто скопировали неудачно).

Comment: смотрите я записал в фаил но там честно говоря месиво, почти без тегов.

Comment: @Stasinskii: неверно сделали. Я написал *"сохранить результат get_html()"*. Так как я вижу только вопрос (в это время у вас `get_html()` делал `urlopen().read()`), то следовало использовать именно ту версию, которая у вас в вопросе на тот момент была опубликована. А вы вместо этого пытаетесь `soup.text` сохранить. Сохраните ваш url в файл `with open('input.html', 'wb') as f: f.write(urlopen(url).read())`. Передайте его в `BeautifulSoup(open('input.html', encoding='utf-8'))` Если не получили номер, то глазами посмотрите на `input.html` (прочтите вопросы в предыдущем комментарии)